# WordPress: Themes conflicts and overrides my WordPress Support widget Plugin styles

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

The front end of the widget plugin has the widget launcher and once opened, it shows the actual widget with its elements. it has lots of styling issues which are 100% from whichever theme is currently active on the site. most of the styles get influenced and this is overridden by whichever theme is running and thus add its own styles to my widget. how can I make the widget 100% independent and only show its own styles without any interference from themes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.